# Add User with specific role id [CakePHP]

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to build a section where we can add users with `Role_ID=2`

`Role_ID` is in some other table named as `User_Details`, and is linked with current `user` table `id` as foreign key.

**Here is code for my UserController.php**

```
function addUser(){

        $this->set('setTab','addUser');
        $this->set('parent_tab','Manage Users');
        $this->set('tab','Add User');


        // Super admin doesn't have an access of Manage user section
        if($this->Session->read('User.access_rights') == 4){
            $this->redirect('dashboard');
        }

        $this->layout = 'user';
        $this->set('setTab','manageUsers');
        $this->set('statusArray', $this->statusArray);

        /*CREATE USER DROP DOWN ARRAY START*/
        /*$userDrop['0']='Select Parent';
        $getUsers = $this->User->generatetreelist('User.access_rights <> 4',null,'{n}.User.username','-');
        if($getUsers) {
            foreach ($getUsers as $key=>$value){
                $userDrop[$key] = $value;
            }
            $this->set(compact('userDrop'));
        }*/
        /*CREATE USER DROP DOWN ARRAY END*/

        if(!$this->Session->check('User')){
            $this->redirect('login');
        }

        if($this->data){
                    $data = $this->data;
                    $this->User->set($data);

                    if ($this->User) {
                        // pr($this->data); die;

                                //  because we like to send pretty mail
                                    //Set view variables as normal

                                     $this->set('userDetails', $data['User']);

                                    //$this->User->recursive = 1;

                                    if($this->User->saveAll($data)){

                                        $this->Session->setFlash('User added successfully', 'default', array('class' => 'errMsgLogin'));
                                        $this->redirect('manageUsers');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "User not added";
                                    }
                    }

                    else {

                        // do nothing
                    }
        }
    }//Ends here
```

Here is code for model **user.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel{
          var $name = "User";





         var $validate = array(
        'Username' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'required' => false,
                'message' => 'Username can not be empty!',
            ), 
             'maxLength'=> array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 20),
                'message' => 'Username can not be longer that 20 characters.'
             )
        ),
        'First_Name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'First name can not be empty!',
                )
        ),
        /*'phone' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'message' => 'Numbers only'
        ),
            'rule' => array('minLength', 10),
            'message' => 'Phone number should be of 10 digits'
        ),*/
        'Last_Name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Last name can not be empty!',
                )
        ),

        'Email_Id' => array(
             'notempty' => array(
             'rule' => array('email'),
             'allowEmpty' => false,
             'message' => 'Please Enter a valid Email Address'
                )
        )
        /*'status'=> array(
             'notempty' => array(
             'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
             'allowEmpty' => false,
             'message' => 'Please Enter a Status'
                )
        ),*/
);
```

Here is view code **add_user.ctp**

```
<h4 class="widgettitle">Add New User</h4>
<div class="widgetcontent">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url'=>'addUser/', "enctype" => "multipart/form-data",'class'=>'stdform','id'=>'form1')); ?>
        <div class="par control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First Name*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('First_Name',array('label'=>false, 'id'=>'firstname','class'=>'input-large')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Last_Name',array('label'=>false,'id'=>'lastname','class'=>'input-large')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Username',array('label'=>false,'id'=>'username','class'=>'input-large')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="par control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Email_Id',array('label'=>false,'id'=>'email','class'=>'input-xlarge')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="par control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="location">Office Phone*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('User_Phone1',array('label'=>false, 'maxlength'=>false,'id'=>'phone','class'=>'input-large')); ?>
            </div> 
        </div>
            <div class="par control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="location">Cell Phone*</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('User_Phone2',array('label'=>false, 'maxlength'=>false,'id'=>'phone','class'=>'input-large')); ?>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="par control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="status">Status</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Is_Active',array('type'=>'select', 'width' => 100, 'options'=>$statusArray, 'label' => false, 'class'=>'input-large')); ?>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <p class="stdformbutton">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </p>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div><!--widgetcontent-->
```

**After adding:**

```
$this->User->bindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('UserDetail'=>array('className' => 'UserDetail', 'foreignKey' => 'Role_ID', ))));
```

**Got Error in query:**

```
SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`User_ID`, `User`.`First_Name`, `User`.`Last_Name`, `User`.`Email_Id`, `User`.`Username`, `User`.`User_Password`, `User`.`User_Phone1`, `User`.`User_Phone2`, `User`.`Created_By`, `User`.`Created_Date`, `User`.`Is_Active`, `User`.`Is_Deleted`, `UserDetail`.`User_Detail_ID`, `UserDetail`.`User_ID`, `UserDetail`.`Role_ID`, `UserDetail`.`Unit_ID`, `UserDetail`.`Rank_ID`, `UserDetail`.`City_ID`, `UserDetail`.`State_ID`, `UserDetail`.`RSID`, `UserDetail`.`User_Address1`, `UserDetail`.`User_Address2`, `UserDetail`.`Zip_Code`, `UserDetail`.`User_Url`, `UserDetail`.`Created_By`, `UserDetail`.`Created_Date`, `UserDetail`.`Is_Active`, `UserDetail`.`Is_Deleted` FROM `national`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `national`.`user_details` AS `UserDetail` ON (`User`.`Role_ID` = `UserDetail`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `User`.`User_ID` DESC
```

Any suggestions on how can I build this?

Comment: please share user model and view code

Comment: More details entered in question. @apuravgaur

Answer (score 0):

You can use bindModel  functionality for associate or link two table like this

$this->User->bindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('UserDetail'=>array('className' => 'UserDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'Role_ID',
            ))));
Now when you find the data of User table than it show the userdetail data also.
You can also use containable behaviour if you want particular field of userdetail model

First check table name of userdetail if your table name like userdetails than you can use class name in bindModel like this Userdetails 
if you  use the table name like this user_details than put class name like this  UserDetails  .Can You give  a function where you find the user data and use bind model  function in particular function .Model should be loaded

Please check table name

Answer (score 0):

Please update User model Code :-

**User Model User.php**

```
  <?php
    class User extends AppModel{
         var $name = "User";

         /**
         * Model associations: hasOne
         *
         * @var array
         * @access public
         */
        public $hasOne = array(
            'UserDetail'
        );

         var $validate = array(
            'Username' => array(
                'notempty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'message' => 'Username can not be empty!',
                ), 
                 'maxLength'=> array(
                    'rule' => array('maxLength', 20),
                    'message' => 'Username can not be longer that 20 characters.'
                 )
            ),
            'First_Name' => array(
                'notempty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    'message' => 'First name can not be empty!',
                    )
            ),
            /*'phone' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'numeric',
                'message' => 'Numbers only'
            ),
                'rule' => array('minLength', 10),
                'message' => 'Phone number should be of 10 digits'
            ),*/
            'Last_Name' => array(
                'notempty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notempty'),
                    'message' => 'Last name can not be empty!',
                    )
            ),

            'Email_Id' => array(
                 'notempty' => array(
                 'rule' => array('email'),
                 'allowEmpty' => false,
                 'message' => 'Please Enter a valid Email Address'
                    )
            )
            /*'status'=> array(
                 'notempty' => array(
                 'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                 'allowEmpty' => false,
                 'message' => 'Please Enter a Status'
                    )
            ),*/
            );
    }
```

Then update controller code

**Here is code for UserController.php**

```
function addUser(){

        $this->set('setTab','addUser');
        $this->set('parent_tab','Manage Users');
        $this->set('tab','Add User');


        // Super admin doesn't have an access of Manage user section
        if($this->Session->read('User.access_rights') == 4){
            $this->redirect('dashboard');
        }

        $this->layout = 'user';
        $this->set('setTab','manageUsers');
        $this->set('statusArray', $this->statusArray);

        /*CREATE USER DROP DOWN ARRAY START*/
        /*$userDrop['0']='Select Parent';
        $getUsers = $this->User->generatetreelist('User.access_rights <> 4',null,'{n}.User.username','-');
        if($getUsers) {
            foreach ($getUsers as $key=>$value){
                $userDrop[$key] = $value;
            }
            $this->set(compact('userDrop'));
        }*/
        /*CREATE USER DROP DOWN ARRAY END*/

        if(!$this->Session->check('User')){
            $this->redirect('login');
        }

        if($this->data){
                    $data = $this->data;
                    $this->User->set($data);

                    if ($this->User) {
                        // pr($this->data); die;

                                //  because we like to send pretty mail
                                    //Set view variables as normal

                                     $this->set('userDetails', $data['User']);

                                    //$this->User->recursive = 1;
                                    $data['UserDetail']['Role_ID'] = 2;
                                    if($this->User->saveAll($data)){

                                        $this->Session->setFlash('User added successfully', 'default', array('class' => 'errMsgLogin'));
                                        $this->redirect('manageUsers');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "User not added";
                                    }
                    }

                    else {

                        // do nothing
                    }
        }
    }//Ends here
```

Comment: Got error Notice (8): Undefined variable: data [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 1137]

Comment: which cakephp version you are using ?